# How To Do This With Notification In Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications

I want set up background of notification like this below image: [[image: Here is example I want to achieve]]
But I got this result like this below image: [[image: Here is result I got]]

Here is my code like the result I got in android kotlin:

```
 val notification = androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(data.name)
            .setContentText(data.author)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentIntent(dataAction.intent)
            .setPriority(androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setVisibility(androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setColorized(true)
            .setCategory(AUDIO_SERVICE)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setLargeIcon(largeBitmap)//this code set image bitmap to entire background notification
            .setStyle(
                NotificationCompat.MediaStyle().setMediaSession(mediaSessionCompat.sessionToken)
            )
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_previous, "Previous", dataAction.previous)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_pause, "Play", dataAction.play)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_next, "Next", dataAction.next)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_exit, "Exit", dataAction.exit)
            .build()
        startForeground(1, notification)
```

First time, I think my image got blur and low quality but when I set up to ImageView, or toBigPictureStyle for testing,and My Image is very clear.

I used `setLargeIcon` because it is the only code I have found that allows me to set an image as the background of a notification.

Then I found some code about custom layout for notification in Android 12, Android 13.

`val contentView = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.notification_layout)`

```
         notification.setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedMediaCustomViewStyle())
         notification.setCustomContentView(contentView)
```

My custom layout notification

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayoutNotification"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/testimg" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`And result is my notification not showing when use above code`.

Someone know how can I set up image cover enitre notification like Spotify or SoundCloud  ?

New Edit 1:
This is about data bitmap when set up for setLargeIcon
With image get from drawable: I tested image with resolution 2048x2048 and convert to Bitmap like this: (And backgroud notification still blur )

```
val withDrawable = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.testimg)
```

with image get from embedded image of file

```
val path ="/storage/emulated/0/Download/Ahhhhhhh/Glichery - Sea Of Problems.mp3"
val withEmbededImage = getAudioFileAlbumArt(path)


fun getAudioFileAlbumArt(filePath: String): Bitmap? {
    val retriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()

    try {
        retriever.setDataSource(filePath)

        val rawArt = retriever.embeddedPicture
        if (rawArt != null) {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawArt, 0, rawArt.size)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        retriever.release()
    }
    return null
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the image you are using is good quality ? Maybe the blur effect is due to bad image resolution. Your code seems fine to me, +1 waiting for someone to answer!

Comment: Can you also add how largeBitmap is declared and init ?

Comment: I just updated for my question @ItzDavi

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, taken from here: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/expanded

```
var notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
    // Show controls on lock screen even when user hides sensitive content.
    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_player)
    // Add media control buttons that invoke intents in your media service
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_prev, "Previous", prevPendingIntent) // #0
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_pause, "Pause", pausePendingIntent) // #1
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_next, "Next", nextPendingIntent) // #2
    // Apply the media style template
    .setStyle(MediaNotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
            .setShowActionsInCompactView(1 /* #1: pause button \*/)
            .setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken()))
    .setContentTitle("Wonderful music")
    .setContentText("My Awesome Band")
    .setLargeIcon(albumArtBitmap)
    .build()
```

Comment: I tried your code before. If I use setStyle with BigPictureStyle like that Notification layout will be get order layout like: Name of App, then Title below, then Content below, then Big Picture below, then Few Action below Big Picture. And it not same like notification of first Image in my question :(

Comment: From you new edit, I read that document, so my code like that document 100% bro, but seem like image example about "Create a notification with media controls" used for low Android version like 2 years ago,

Comment: It was last updated start of 2023, but different phone models handle and show notifications differently. Have you tried running it on a different model?

Comment: The layout of notifications on Android 13 remains the same when tested on the actual devices, Google Pixel 7 Pro and Poco X3 Pro. In both cases, the notifications display a blurred background image. However, when using Spotify and SoundCloud on these devices, the background notifications appear very clear.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the image you are using?

Comment: The image I showed in my question, It got 2048x2048, I tried other images like 3840x2160, 2932x2932,....etc.... and result still blur

Comment: Try both of these resolutions and let me know: 1440x720, 2880x1440

Comment: Confirm, nothing new bro, still blur :(